# Request for data dump to contain userid of closers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump

Currently the data dump, the "votes" table contains rows that record votes to close (or reopen) a question, but the userid column is not filled in for these votes. Since this information is available on the web interface (just go look at the question history online), this data should be available in the data dump as well.

Comment: I guess they wanted to be careful not to disclose non-effective close votes but were too lazy to actually distinguish them and include the safe votes.

Comment: @Fearless: actually the vote table is mostly anonymous except for a few specific kinds of votes (a favorite vote is one). I don't think there's any need to hide close votes that don't yet have enough support to become actionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next data dump will contain PostHistory for every action that occurs on a post which  includes close votes, undeletes, and reopeners. Please see [Anatomy of a Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump) for a description of all the fields.

Comment: Ooh, this is gonna be interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Excellent feature request, to add to it:

The Deleters, Undeleters, and Re-openers should be added as well.

Comment: Downvoted? *Why*? What is good for the goose is not good for the gander?

Comment: I agree with this - it's all public on the site, so it should be in the dump as well. *Especially* if closing is attributed.